Кириллица в pg_trgm триграмах postgres
Хочу сохранить триграммы в текстовой строке. Для этого выполняю запрос:
SELECT id, show_trgm(name) FROM basistypes;
Русские буквы выдаются в виде кодов, хотя английские нормально:

Как можно получить буквы вместо кодов?

Попробуйте привести явно к TEXT. Ну что-то типа convert_from(bytea_value, 'UTF8')
